# Right code but still test case is not running in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given an array of ints, return True if .. 1, 2, 3, .. appears in the array somewhere.

```
def array123(nums):
    for i in  nums:
       if nums[i:i+3] == [1,2,3]:
          return True
    return False
```

[Coding bat problem](http://codingbat.com/prob/p193604)

my code is satisfying all the test cases except for nums=[1,2,3]
can someone tell me whats wrong with my code

Comment: You are getting False?

Comment: The code isn't right: `i` is a value in `nums`, not an index.

Comment: I also want Value in nums,  not the index

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not completely right. You're slicing the list with the items in the list, not with indices. Luckily, this did not throw any error because the items in the list are within the bounds of the list's indices or rather *slicing* does not raise errors, when done correclty, irrespective of start and/or stop indices.

You can use `range(len(...))` to generate the indices, and you may stop the search at `len(nums) - len(sublist)`, so you don't check for *slices* less than the length of the *sublist*. This comes more handy as the length of the *sublist* gets larger.

```
def array123(nums, sublist):
    j = len(sublist)
    for i in range(len(nums)-j):
       if nums[i:i+j] == sublist:
          return True
    return False

# Call function
array123(nums, [1,2,3])
```

---

Useful reference:

[Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation)

Comment: I don't  understand the part "slicing the list with the items in the list, not with indices"  . Can you explain

Comment: @Duck_dragon `for i in  nums` iterates on elements in the list, and doing `nums[i:i+3]` uses those elements as *slice indices*

Comment: But then if this is happening behind the scenes then why i am getting correct answers for all the previous problems. And in this one also. Only the thing is that one test case is not working and rest all are working.

Comment: can you provide me with a link where i can read about slicing indices and elements in list

Comment: also len(nums) is giving me error:list index out of range while len(nums)-2 is not can you explain why

Comment: This would help with understanding slicing: [Explain Python's slice notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation)

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this.

```
def array123(nums):
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        if nums[i:i+3] == [1,2,3]:
            return True
    return False
```

Try this. Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're getting wrong result because you're iterating on the value of elements not on the index of elements of elements. Try following code

```
def array123(nums):
    for i in range(len(nums)-2):
       if nums[i:i+3] == [1,2,3]:
          return True
    return False
```

And remember to give the end index of list (range(len(nums)-2)) because suppose if length of your array is 4 then (range(len(nums)-2))  will be

(range(2)) = [0,1]

So the loop will iterate for 0,1 as starting index

Comment: Why you are using len(nums)-2 or num[:-2] what is this concept .why i can't just iterate over the list as whole

Comment: also len(nums) is giving me error:list index out of range while len(nums)-2 is not can you explain why

Comment: because let's suppose len(nums)=5 then if you have len(nums) in place of (len(nums)-2) then range(len(nums))=[0,1,2,3,4] and next line in loop nums[i:i+3] = nums[4:4+3] for last index 4 and thus nums[4:7] which is not possible because nums contain elements only till 4th index.